# How to properly import CSV with data into Excel 2019 (decimal separator)

Tags: excel, csv

I have a CSV file structured as below:

```
TimeStamp,AccelerationPedalPos,AccelerationX,AccelerationY,AccelerationZ,Altitude,AltitudeAccuracy,AltitudeValid,AngularRateX,AngularRateY,AngularRateZ,AttitudeValid,BattCoolingLiquidInlet,BattCoolingLiquidOutlet,BattTempMain,BatteryTotalChargeHV,BatteryTotalDischargeHV,BatteryVoltageHV,Co2ContentInterior,Current,DistanceAccuracy,DistanceTotal,DistanceTrip,DistanceValid,EVSpeed,Epoch,Fence1,Fence2,Fence3,Fence4,FenceCombined,FenceValid,FixType,Heading,HeadingAccuracy,ImuValid,IndoorTemp,Latitude,Longitude,Odometer,OutdoorTemp,Pitch,PitchAccuracy,PositionAccuracy,PositionValid,Roll,RollAccuracy,Satellites,Speed,SpeedAccuracy,SpeedValid,StateOfChargeBMS,TimeConfirmed,TimeValid,Voltage
2023-01-09 11:17:40+00:00,53.333333334,,,,,,,,,,,18.0,18.0,18.0,500320.5802161523,505.7552105152147,377.0,600.0,72.5625,,,,,0.0,,,,,,,,,,,,18.6,,,1197.0,18.0,,,,,,,,,,,73.6,,,14.416015625
2023-01-09 11:17:45+00:00,53.333333334,-2.801598837209302,4.017926356589148,4.6082848837209305,-5400.0,0.0,0.0,10.743701550387597,-9.150193798449612,-9.817829457364342,0.0,19.0,18.0,18.0,500320.5799831355,505.7552105152147,377.0,600.0,55.25,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,1577840400.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,18.6,56.15350500000001,10.177122,1197.0,18.0,0.0,0.0,45.2,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,73.6,0.0,0.0,13.76953125
2023-01-09 11:17:50+00:00,53.333333334,-8.670036764705882,1.6387867647058822,4.673253676470588,-5400.0,0.0,0.0,-6.926470588235294,7.5275735294117645,-3.9949448529411766,0.0,18.0,18.0,18.0,500320.57986662706,505.7552105152147,377.0,500.0,50.5,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,1577840400.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,18.6,56.15350500000001,10.177122,1197.0,18.0,0.0,0.0,56.8,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,73.6,0.0,0.0,13.666015625
2023-01-09 11:17:55+00:00,53.333333334,-8.625,1.5,4.75,-5400.0,0.0,0.0,-0.7495395948434622,-0.2504604051565378,-0.4976979742173112,0.0,18.0,18.0,18.0,500320.57963361026,505.7552105152147,377.0,500.0,50.9375,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,1577840400.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,18.6,56.15350500000001,10.177122,1197.0,18.0,0.0,0.0,63.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,73.6,0.0,0.0,13.7734375
2023-01-09 11:18:00+00:00,53.333333334,-8.625459558823529,1.4825367647058822,4.754825367647059,-5400.0,0.0,0.0,-0.7201286764705882,-0.2734375,-0.48391544117647056,0.0,18.0,18.0,18.0,500320.57951710187,505.7552105152147,377.0,500.0,48.9375,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,1577840400.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,18.8,56.15350500000001,10.177122,1197.0,18.0,0.0,0.0,63.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,73.6,0.0,0.0,13.783203125
2023-01-09 11:18:05+00:00,53.333333334,-8.616987179487179,1.4081959706959708,4.833562271062271,-5400.0,0.0,0.0,-0.695054945054945,-0.2760989010989011,-0.4308608058608059,0.0,18.0,18.0,18.0,500320.579284085,505.7552105152147,377.0,500.0,49.75,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,1577840400.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,18.8,56.15350500000001,10.177122,1197.0,18.0,0.0,0.0,63.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,73.6,0.0,0.0,13.888671875
2023-01-09 11:18:10+00:00,53.333333334,-8.607306985294118,1.4076286764705883,4.863740808823529,-5400.0,0.0,0.0,-0.7247242647058824,-0.21645220588235295,-0.40625,0.0,18.0,18.0,18.0,500320.5791675766,505.7552105152147,377.0,500.0,50.3125,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,1577840400.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,18.8,56.15350500000001,10.177122,1197.0,18.0,0.0,0.0,63.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,73.6,0.0,0.0,13.94921875
2023-01-09 11:18:15+00:00,53.333333334,-8.594439338235293,1.396829044117647,4.8713235294117645,-5400.0,0.0,0.0,-0.7284007352941176,-0.25827205882352944,-0.3616727941176471,0.0,18.0,18.0,18.0,500320.5789345598,505.7552105152147,377.0,500.0,51.5625,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,1577840400.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,19.0,56.15350500000001,10.177122,1197.0,18.0,0.0,0.0,63.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,73.6,0.0,0.0,13.978515625
2023-01-09 11:18:20+00:00,53.333333334,-8.574770642201836,1.3892201834862385,4.886697247706422,-5400.0,0.0,0.0,-0.5926605504587156,-0.24311926605504589,-0.65,0.0,18.0,18.0,18.0,500320.5788180514,505.7552105152147,377.0,500.0,52.125,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,1577840400.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,19.0,56.15350500000001,10.177122,1197.0,18.0,0.0,0.0,63.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,73.6,0.0,0.0,14.08984375
2023-01-09 11:18:25+00:00,53.333333334,-9.67988929889299,1.5970940959409594,1.264760147601476,-5400.0,0.0,0.0,3.9321955719557193,4.131457564575646,-0.6088560885608856,0.0,18.0,18.0,18.0,500320.5785850345,505.7552105152147,377.0,500.0,50.375,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,1577840400.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,19.0,56.15350500000001,10.177122,1197.0,18.0,0.0,0.0,63.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,73.6,0.0,0.0,14.083984375
2023-01-09 11:18:30+00:00,53.333333334,-9.848443223443223,1.87110805
```

When I try to load this into Excel 2019, Excel fails to automatically detect the correct value types. For example, I want `AccelerationPedalPos` to correct be interpreted as a number with `.` being the decimal separator. However, instead Excel treats it as an integer, i.e. `53333333334` instead of `53.333333334`.

Is there a simple way to get Excel to properly detect the decimal separator in this case - without having to manually specify it for each column? I realize I can manually assign datatypes, but this is extremely time consuming.

Note: If I open the CSV file with Excel by right-clicking it and selecting Open with, then it loads all data correctly - so this appears to be a specific issue in the data import functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the decimal separator during import here:

[image]

You don't have to specify the datatypes for each column except when there are numbers which you want interpreted as text.

Also if your csv has the same format every time, you could easily record a macro, tweak it a little bit and use that to import data so that all the setup is done for you. Something like (this should work for your CSV):

```vba
Sub importData()
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Dim path As String
    path = Application.GetOpenFilename
    If path = "False" Then Exit Sub
    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;" & path, Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
        .Name = "csvData"
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFilePlatform = 852
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, _
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        .TextFileDecimalSeparator = "."
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The challenge is that I am trying to solve this on behalf of a large number of individual end users. Further, the wizard you show is pre Excel 2019. The more recent wizard looks different